# Encoding an EPC for the ZPL ZD500R Printer

Tags: ios, printing, zpl

I am using the following page as a helper:

http://www.tharo.com/documents/tech582.htm

On that page the EPC is broken down into the bits that need to be passed to the printer in ZPL.
Based off that I have used the following ZPL and sent it to the printer:

```
^XA
^RB96,8,3,3,20,24,38^FS
^RFW,E^FD48,3,5,0614141,100041,1^FS
^XZ
```

Unfortunately I do not get the same EPC written to the tag as outlined in the document.

**Update**: I am using the Zebra iOS SDK to encode the tags. In their documentation the ZPL is all in one line.

Comment: Why do you have a `^FS` between the `^RB` and `^RF`?  And the `^FS` following `^FD` should be on the same line.

Comment: Sorry, I formatted it for readability. In my iOS code though the entire command is a single line. Would that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look to the authoritative standards for this one.  See the [TDS Standard from GS1 (p92 and p132)](http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/TDS_1_9_Standard.pdf) for details on the format, and [the ZPL programming manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=401) for the printer.

To summarize, the data you are encoding is:

- Header: SGTIN-96
  8 bits, decimal 48
- Filter: 3
  3 bits, decimal 3
- Partition: 24 bit company / 20 bit item
  3 bits, decimal 5
- Company: 0614141
  24 bits, decimal 0614141
- Item: 100041
  20 bits, decimal 100041
- Serial: 1
  38 bits, decimal 1

So the ZPL should be:

```
^XA
^RB96,8,3,3,24,20,38
^RFW,E^FD48,3,5,0614141,100041,1^FS
^XZ
```

Note that there is no `^FS` between `^RB` and `^RF`, and that partition `5` mandates `24,20`. `20,24` would be partition `6`. The `^RB` is a comma separated list of the field widths, the `^FD` is a comma separated list of the decimal field data.  I will also note that filter `3` is "Reserved".  I would imagine the filter you need to be `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seems though that the data you posted in your answer is the same as mine except the filter value. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you have an extra `^FS`, and the wrong field widths.

Comment: Yup. That was the issue. Just tried it and it worked great.

Comment: hey @Mitch, I am wondering if you see anything with the following ZPL: ^XA^RB96,8,3,3,24,20,38^RFW,E^FD48,1,5,0628722,95783,527849849^FS^XZ